# Can't log in to backend Joomla3 after changing log-path

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

When logging in to the back-end of my website I had the problem of `Cannot open file for writing log`. After finding the solution to this error and solving it by changing the log path's, i encountered the following problem: `not able to login`. I get the error that login name and password is incorrect.

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear browser cache;
2. Look in your configuration file /configuration.php around line 55 ~ 60 if the folder was correct;

   public $log_path = '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/logs';

   public $tmp_path = '/home/xxxxxx/public_html/tmp';

*This file path structure was in cPanel